# Ampersand-rest-collection using multiple url end points

Tags: rest, backbone.js, ampersand.js

In standard ampersand-rest-collection you define the url endpoint as a property and [getOr]Fetch() queries using that url.

I have two endpoints for the same model. Essentially, when I am pulling a list of objects I use one url end point, but when I am pulling individual objects I need to use a different one. Is it possible to tell fetch() which url to use in each case?

```
DocStore = _.extend(docs, {
    url: [could this be an object or array?]
    getOne: function(docId) {
        return this.fetchById(docId); //should use /doc/:docId
    },
    getMany: function(groupId) {
        return DocStore.getOrFetch(groupId); //should use /group/:groupId/docs
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like many backbone properties you can use a function for the [url](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url) property instead of a string to return whatever dynamic result you need.

For example you can do something like the following

```
url : function () {
 return this.fetchingMany ? '/group/' : '/doc'
},

getOne: function(docId) {
  this.fetchingMany = false;
  this.fetch(); //should use /doc/:docId
},
getMany: function(groupId) {
   this.fetchingMany = true;
   this.fetch(); //should use /group/:groupId/docs
}
```

Comment: Do you see a problem with the additional docs at the end for the getMany (/group/:groupId/docs)? I am new to ampersand and I don't know how it is building up the urls.

Comment: To be honest I haven't used ampersand at all, I was just answering how you can dynamically change the URL used for fetch based on whatever logic you have.

Comment: I didn't think to look but there is more info in the ampersand-model docs - https://github.com/AmpersandJS/ampersand-model#url-modelurl-or-modelurl